# ¿Unión o concatenación de dos switch?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

¿Cómo puedo hacer para unir dos `switch`, ambos con sus respectivos `case`?

En este caso, hago uso de dos **picturebox** (es necesario hacer uso de estos por petición del cliente, ya que será una aplicación muy gráfica) por medio de los cuales, se seleccionará la edad, llamados `Edad 1` y `Edad 2` en los cuales al ir dando click irán cambiando los números del `0` al `9` hasta que el usuario ajuste su edad.

Ejemplo `Edad 1 = 2` y `Edad 2 = 5`, entonces `Edad = 25`, posteriormente la edad final, la quiero almacenar en un `Datatable`, es por eso que me gustaría saber de qué manera puedo unir ambos `switch` para que la edad final se vea como un solo número en el `datatable`.

*Nota*: La aplicación es en *C#* con *Visual studio*.

Código:

```
private void Edad1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(a)
    {

        case 1:
            Edad1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "/uno.png");
            a = a + 1;
            break;

        case 2:
            Edad1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "/dos.png");
            a = a + 1;
            Edad1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            break;

        case 3:
            Edad1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "/tres.png");
            a = a + 1;
            break;

        case 4:
            Edad1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "/cuatro.png");
            a = a + 1;
            break;

        case 5:
            Edad1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "/cinco.png");
            a = a + 1;
            break;

        case 6:
            Edad1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "/seis.png");
            a = a + 1;
            break;

        case 7:
            Edad1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "/siete.png");
            a = a + 1;
            break;

        case 8:
            Edad1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "/ocho.png");
            a = a + 1;
            break;

        case 9:
            Edad1.Image = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "/nueve.png");
            a = a + 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Si pusieras los switchs que quieres unir sería más fácil ayudarte. Por lo que he leído es tan simple como coger los `values` de cada uno y tener la edad final como `Edad1`*10 + `Edad2` así que supongo que me estoy perdiendo algo.

Comment: ¿De dónde viene la variable `a` y para que la vas a usar? ¿El código de `Edad2` es igual o usas otra variable?

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta de @LeandroTuttini se agradecería que la aceptaras para que otros en la comunidad puedan aprovecharse de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Aconsejaria no uses switch, puedes mapear las imagenes con el valor numerico usando un Dictionary<>, entonces seria

```
Dictionary<int, string> ImageList = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    {1, "uno.png"},
    {2, "dos.png"},
    {3, "tres.png"},
    //resto
};
```

entonces puedes hacer

```
 string imgFile = ImageList[a];
 string imgPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, imgFile);

 Edad1.Image = Image.FromFile(imgPath);
```

asi de simple sin ninguna switch, puedes tomar segun la key del diccionario que imagen mapea con el valor numerico

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora una pregunta... para concatenar(unir) ambas edades tanto de la Edad1 y Edad2 para que formen una sola al final, ejemplo: Edad1= 2 y Edad2 =5 entonces EDAD = 25.
Y  posteriormente pasarla a un datatable??

Comment: Como dijo @Awes0meM4n, es muy simple con la siguiente operación:

EDAD = Edad1*10 + Edad2